# different accuracy results for tf data dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have loaded a pretrained model as seen below :

```
model.load_weights('..')
```

and i have a test set of type :

```
<BatchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128, 128, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))>
```

Using :

```
model.evaluate(test_set)
```

i get 68% accuracy.

However i also do the above process manually :

```
true_labels= tf.concat([y for x, y in test_set], axis=0)
test_set = test_set.map(lambda x,y : x) # only keeping attributes
predicted_labels = tf.argmax(model.predict(test_set), axis=1)
print('acc ', accuracy_score(res_labels, true_labels))
```

which produces an acucracy of 29%.
Aren't the above procedures the same?
Why is this happening?

Comment: Your dataset is shuffled every time you iterate over it.

Comment: @AloneTogether So after the first line in the last code box test_set is shuffled?

Comment: Yes exactly....

Comment: One more thing, i changed the code a bit based on this and still result in similar behaviour. Is the dataset shuffled after each iterative step or after each iteration procedure?(i.e. for the first line in the last code block is test_set shuffled once or len(list(test_set)) times)?

Comment: Can you up your question with how you defined your dataset? It should be just setting the parameter `shuffle=False`.